# Prove $fg$ homogeneous implies both $f$ and $g$ homogeneous

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics, polynomials

Suppose $f,g$ are polynomials in $\Bbb K^n$ where $\Bbb K$ is a number field (namely $\Bbb Q\subset \Bbb K$). If $fg$ is a [homogeneous polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_polynomial) then how to (slickly) prove both $f$ and $g$ are homogeneous?

Well, one hopeful way is to group the terms of $f$ by their total orders and do the same for $g$, then their respective highest order terms should multiply into terms whose orders are strictly greater than terms multiplied from other groups. Is there any other slick approach?

Comment: use the fact that $P(\lambda x_1, \ldots, \lambda x_n) =\lambda^d P( x_1, \ldots, x_n) $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's maybe easier to see the converse.

We can decompose any polynomial into its homogeneous parts: For $f, g \neq 0$, write $$f = f_a + f_{a + 1} + \cdots + f_{b - 1} + f_b , \qquad g_c + g_{c + 1} + \cdots + g_{d - 1} + g_d,$$ where $f_i$, $g_i$ are homogeneous of degree $i$ (and these representations are minimal in the sense that $f_a, f_b, g_c, g_d$ are nonzero). The lowest- and highest- degree homogeneous parts of $fg$ have degree $a + c$ and $b + d$, but if, e.g., $f$ is not homogeneous, then $a < b$, and so $a + c < b + d$, i.e., $fg$ is not homogeneous.

Comment: Yeah that's what I am thinking about. Group the terms by their total order.

Answer (score 2):

You can use any field $F$. In the sequel, $\mathbf{x}$ stands for $(x_1,\dots,x_n)$. Write
\begin{align}
f(\mathbf{x})&=f_0(\mathbf{x})+f_1(\mathbf{x})+\dots+f_r(\mathbf{x})\\
g(\mathbf{x})&=g_0(\mathbf{x})+g_1(\mathbf{x})+\dots+g_s(\mathbf{x})
\end{align}
where $f_k$ and $g_k$ are homogeneous of degree $k$. Suppose $fg$ is homogeneous of degree $n$. Then, by definition,
$$
f(t\mathbf{x})g(t\mathbf{x})=t^nf(\mathbf{x})g(\mathbf{x})
$$
where $t$ is an indeterminate over $F[\mathbf{x}]$. Thus we have
$$
t^n
\biggl(\,\sum_{h}f_h(\mathbf{x})\biggr)
\biggl(\,\sum_{k}g_k(\mathbf{x})\biggr)
=
\biggl(\,\sum_{h}t^hf_h(\mathbf{x})\biggr)
\biggl(\,\sum_{k}t^kg_k(\mathbf{x})\biggr)
$$
Equate the coefficients.